# Cсылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#

Можете подсказать, почему объект не инициализирован, что я делал не так? Использую библиотеку `dotNetRDF`, подключил ее через Ссылки--Добавить ссылки. При выполнении сначала запрашивает файл `TreeIndexedTripleCollection.cs` (не знаю откуда он его взял вообще). Потом на строчке `Graph g = new Graph();` выдает такую ошибку "ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта". Этот код взят с сайта как пример.

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using VDS.RDF;

using VDS.RDF.Writing;

public class HelloWorld 
{
    public static void Main(String[] args) 
    {

        Graph g = new Graph();

        IUriNode dotNetRDF = g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create("http://www.dotnetrdf.org"));
        IUriNode says = g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create("http://example.org/says"));
        ILiteralNode helloWorld = g.CreateLiteralNode("Hello World");
        ILiteralNode bonjourMonde = g.CreateLiteralNode("Bonjour tout le Monde", "fr");

        g.Assert(new Triple(dotNetRDF, says, helloWorld));
        g.Assert(new Triple(dotNetRDF, says, bonjourMonde));

        foreach (Triple t in g.Triples)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
        }

        NTriplesWriter ntwriter = new NTriplesWriter();
        ntwriter.Save(g, "HelloWorld.nt");

        RdfXmlWriter rdfxmlwriter = new RdfXmlWriter();
        rdfxmlwriter.Save(g, "HelloWorld.rdf");

    }
}
```

Comment: Извините, кто у кого и когда запрашивает файл `TreeIndexedTripleCollection.cs`? Что означает "ошибка" — исключение? Если да, какого типа, что лежит в поле `StackTrace`?

Comment: Файл запрашивает он у меня)

Comment: Эээ... Кто это "он"? (Только не говорите "компьютер", ладно?) Каким образом запрашивает?

Comment: Компилятор) Открывается окошко открытия файла

Comment: Компилятор обычно является утилитой комстроки и вряд ли запрашивает у вас файл. А вот IDE может, но это уж точно нерелевантно к проблеме. Попробуйте сократить исходный код до такого:

    public static void Main(String[] args) 
    {
        Graph g = new Graph();
    }

Если проблема воспроизводится, поделитесь с нами всеми подробностями по выброшенному исключению.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего для работы библиотеки нужно больше одной `dll`, а Вы подключили одну, ну или не все.

Советую использовать `Nuget и Package Manager` в `Visual Studio`.
В `VS 2012`: Сервис - Диспетчер пакетов библиотек - Консоль диспетчера пакетов.
в консоли введите **`Install-Package dotNetRDF`**. Это гарантированно установит все нужные библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

```
IGraph g = new Graph();
```

Можно попробовать так. Плюс [пример](https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide/Hello%20World).